# what is the best way to test onCreate with PersistableBundle?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-testing

```
void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState, 
            PersistableBundle persistentState)
```

With this method , it is called when device is rebooted according to the API doc which makes it a hassle to test.

`savedInstanceState` is much easier to test, just wondering is there any mechanism to let the Android system parse `PersistableBundle` back without reboot?
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#persistableMode